# Android Constraint layout - fix view to bottom of page AND below another view (while not being in between)

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a `ConstraintLayout` that's within a `NestedScrollView`. At the bottom of this `ScrollView` (which has `fillViewport="true"`) I always want a button. So I set my button to be `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` and it is correctly fixed to the bottom. However, I have an expandable `RecyclerView` that covers up the button when expanded, since there are no constraints set between the button and the list. If I add `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/expandableRecyclerView"`, the button no longer gets covered - however the button is no longer fixed to the bottom of the page, it lays between the unexpanded list and the bottom of the page.

How can I set these two constraints, but tell the button to prefer being constrained to the bottom of the view? Below you can see the image of the button placed in between with the two constraints. I want it to be fixed to the bottom.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, sorry for posting. After 5 more minutes of tinkering I found that setting `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"` fixes my problem.